# Go-compiled binary won't run in an alpine docker container on Ubuntu host

Tags: go, docker, busybox, alpine-linux

Given a binary, compiled with Go using `GOOS=linux` and `GOARCH=amd64`, deployed to a `docker` container based on `alpine:3.3`, the binary will not run if the docker engine host is Ubuntu (15.10):

```
sh: /bin/artisan: not found
```

This same binary (compiled for the same OS and arch) will **run just fine** if the docker engine host is `busybox` (which is the base for `alpine`) deployed within a VirtualBox VM on Mac OS X.

This same binary will also run perfectly fine if the container is based on one of Ubuntu images.

**Any idea what this binary is missing?**

This is what I've done to reproduce (successful run in VirtualBox/busybox on OS X not shown):

Build (building explicitly with flags even though the arch matches):

```
➜  artisan git:(master) ✗ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

Check it can run on the host:

```
➜  artisan git:(master) ✗ ./artisan 
10:14:04.925 [ERROR] artisan: need a command, one of server, provision or build
```

Copy to docker dir, build, run:

```
➜  artisan git:(master) ✗ cp artisan docker/build/bin/        
➜  artisan git:(master) ✗ cd docker 
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ cat Dockerfile 
FROM docker:1.10
COPY build/ /
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker build -t artisan .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.15 MB
Step 1 : FROM docker:1.10
...
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker run -it artisan sh
/ # /bin/artisan 
sh: /bin/artisan: not found
```

Now changing the image base to `phusion/baseimage`:

```
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ cat Dockerfile 
#FROM docker:1.10
FROM phusion/baseimage
COPY build/ /
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker build -t artisan .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.15 MB
Step 1 : FROM phusion/baseimage
...
➜  docker git:(master) ✗ docker run -it artisan sh
# /bin/artisan
08:16:39.424 [ERROR] artisan: need a command, one of server, provision or build
```

Comment: Does adding CGO_ENABLED=0 help?

Comment: Magic, it does. Could you please elaborate in an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Could you please try `go build -tags netgo -a -v std` with CGO_ENABLED=1? I think it could be issues with the net package, causing dynamic linking.

Comment: As you suggested this helped `CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -tags netgo -a -v`. If I understand correctly in contrast to CGO_ENABLED=0 this will also preserve the TLS functionality in the net package, which otherwise would be lost, is that right? Can I see somehow what is linked into the binary statically and what is left for dynamic linking?

Comment: By default CGO can be used for the net package - using the above tag or CGO_ENABLED=0 forces the Go std implementation for lookups to be used - what you can do is do: `ldd output.bin` on each build variant to see if they're truly statically compiled or if there's any dynamic linking going on.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for help and explanation!

Comment: When you use CGO, the binary is linked against glibc, but alpine uses musl libc. (also, the tls package doesn't use cgo, except to get root certs on darwin)

Comment: This seems similar to the issue that I had and solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729748/installed-go-binary-not-found-in-path-on-alpine-linux-docker/35613430#35613430

Comment: @sheldonk Thanks for the tip. I will give it a try even though linking everything statically would be my preference.

Comment: There are also some alpine glibc base images that you could try out that should solve your issue

Answer (score 121, accepted):

By default, if using the `net` package a build will likely produce a binary with some dynamic linking, e.g. to libc. You can inspect dynamically vs. statically link by viewing the result of `ldd output.bin`

There are two solutions I've come across:

- Disable CGO, via `CGO_ENABLED=0`
- Force the use of the Go implementation of net dependencies, netgo via `go build -tags netgo -a -v`, this is implemented for a certain platforms

From https://golang.org/doc/go1.2:

> The net package requires cgo by default because the host operating system must in general mediate network call setup. On some systems, though, it is possible to use the network without cgo, and useful to do so, for instance to avoid dynamic linking. The new build tag netgo (off by default) allows the construction of a net package in pure Go on those systems where it is possible.

The above assumes that the only CGO dependency is the standard library's `net` package.

Comment: `CGO_ENABLED=0` also fixed my problem: Trying to run alpine-built go program on non-alpine docker. The error in my case just said `docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..`

Comment: For anyone using Bazel, the above can be accomplished with the `--features=static --features=pure` flags.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, took a lot of Googling to find.

Comment: I think another optional solution is copy source code into image and exec go build in image.

Comment: CGO_ENABLED=0 should fix the problem.

This condition is important too, GOARCH=amd64

Comment: It would be great if this answer also included what possible issues the 2 solutions could cause. Are either of them pretty much guaranteed to be safe? Or could they cause other runtime issues when the program tries to execute some of the related code? I'm building someone else's project as a component of my code, so I don't have a ton of insight into the related code that could rely on CGO.

Answer (score 108):

I had the same issue with a go binary, and I got it to work after adding this to my docker file:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
```

Comment: help me to run CGO in my Alpine image

Comment: Saved a lot of time. +1

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me,  and gives `error relocating ...: fprintf chk: symbol not found`

Comment: you need to build and run in the same environment. e.g if you build the binary in your local machine and run it inside docker, it may cause the issue

Comment: I am running someone else's go binary in an Alpine docker container, and I don't want to recompile it myself.  I'd rather use the publicly available binary.  This solution fixes the issue and lets me run the go binary in an Alpine docker container

Comment: Thanks a lot, does it matter where the above command is placed in the Docker-file. Say after which command?

Comment: glad it helps. as long as it's installed before running the binary, it should be ok

Comment: After a struggle of 3 hours, this worked!!! Thanks

Comment: Just for the record - in case you are using multi-stage builds in your Dockerfile, this command is required in the stage where the binary is **run**, not built. That's where it will otherwise fail finding the required dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 12):

Go compiler from your build machine probably links your binary with libraries on different location than in Alpine. In my case it was compiled with dependencies under /lib64 but Alpine does not use that folder.

```
FROM alpine:edge AS build
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --update go=1.8.3-r0 gcc=6.3.0-r4 g++=6.3.0-r4
WORKDIR /app
ENV GOPATH /app
ADD src /app/src
RUN go get server # server is name of our application
RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux go install -a server

FROM alpine:edge
WORKDIR /app
RUN cd /app
COPY --from=build /app/bin/server /app/bin/server
CMD ["bin/server"]
```

I'm working on article about this issue. You can find draft with this solution here https://kefblog.com/Post/2017-07-04_golang-in-docker-without-disabling-cgo-on-alpine .

Comment: `RUN cd /app` is redundant, `WORKDIR` directive automatically sets the current directory to the working directory.

Answer (score 11):

What did the trick for me was enabling static linking in the linker options:

```
$ go build -ldflags '-linkmode external -w -extldflags "-static"'
```

The `-linkmode` option tells Go to use the external linker, the `-extldflags` option sets options to pass to the linker and the `-w` flag disables DWARF debug info to improve binary size.

See `go tool link` and [Statically compiled Go programs, always, even with cgo, using musl](https://dominik.honnef.co/posts/2015/06/statically_compiled_go_programs__always__even_with_cgo__using_musl/)
 for more details

Comment: That works however, its maybe worth pointing out that its also throwing a warning. => `warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking` I guess in case of alpine base image its ok though.

Answer (score 3):

While executing a go binary inside a debian docker container, faced this issue:
`/bin/bash: line 10: /my/go/binary: No such file or directory`

The binary was built by using docker-in-docker (dind) from an alpine container using command:
`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build`

Fixed it by using following env while building the binary:
`CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build`

Answer (score 3):

I had an app that required `CGO_ENABLED=1`.

The fix for me to run the compiled go binary in a debian-slim container was to build the binary using `RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o goapp`

And run the following commands in the debian slim

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y musl-dev
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/libc.so /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
```

Made me able to run the goapp afterwards

TIP: `ldd goapp` showed that libc.musl-x86_64 was missing in the container.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is that the alpine image uses musl libc, and the binary program compiled by cgo relies on gnu libc, so there will be compatibility problems. You can use the ldd command to view the dynamic libraries that a binary depends on.

```
root# ldd main 
 !10807         
  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea7fab000)
  libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f7b1f818000)
  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7b1f5f9000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7b1f208000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7b1fa32000)
```

There are ways around this, go build sets CGO_ENABLED to 0.

```
env CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main main.go
```

In addition, if you insist on using cgo to compile the program, you can use frolvlad/alpine-glibc as the base image to solve this problem.

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
WORKDIR /hello
COPY . .
CMD ["./main"]
```

hope it can help you.