# How to run an executable twice in a container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How do I execute an executable twice in a docker container?

For instance I need to run my application twice, the first time to initialize some stuff, and the second time to listen to a given port defined in an environment variables.

The commands from a shell would be something like this:

```
[j3d@gonzo test]$ kontrol -initial
[j3d@gongo test]$ kontrol
started... listening on port 6000...
```

Here below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.8.3 as builder
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
RUN go get -d github.com/koding/kite
WORKDIR ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/koding/kite
RUN ${GOPATH}/bin/dep ensure
RUN go install ./kontrol/kontrol
RUN mv ${GOPATH}/bin/kontrol /tmp

FROM busybox
ENV APP_HOME /opt/robotrader
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}
COPY --from=builder /tmp/kontrol .
ENTRYPOINT ["./kontrol", "-initial"]
CMD ["./kontrol"]
```

The container builds successfully... but when I start it I always get the following error message:

```
kontrol    | standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to [zero298](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691711/zero298) who helped me to figure out the issue, here below is a working `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.8.3 as builder
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
RUN go get -d github.com/koding/kite
WORKDIR ${GOPATH}/src/github.com/koding/kite
RUN ${GOPATH}/bin/dep ensure
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install ./kontrol/kontrol
RUN mv ${GOPATH}/bin/kontrol /tmp

FROM busybox
ENV APP_HOME /opt/robotrader
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}
COPY --from=builder /tmp/kontrol .
ENTRYPOINT ["./kontrol", "-initial"]
CMD ["./kontrol"]
```

The `go` application should be built with `CGO_ENABLED=0` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279253/go-compiled-binary-wont-run-in-an-alpine-docker-container-on-ubuntu-host) for more info.

Comment: What command are you using to run the container?

Comment: sudo -E docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up &

Comment: Shouldn't it be `kontrol -initial`?  I don't see an `-init` flag.

Comment: Yes... I used `-initial`... here it is just an example... but I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are running into a different issue than you think you are.  Running your Dockerfile and then executing:

```
docker build -t j3d .
docker run -it --rm --name j3d-test --entrypoint sh j3d
```

Allows me to run my own commands from within the container.

Using `ls` lists out the PWD contents:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       16.8M Jun 21 19:20 kontrol
```

Everything seems normal.  However, trying to run that myself generates the following error:

```
sh: ./kontrol: not found
```

To me, this is likely similar to: [Linux executable fails with “File not found” even though the file is there and in PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/378301/167420).

In fact, if you instead:

1. Copy the compiled `kontrol` executable out of your `builder` image
2. Run the ubuntu container mounting the directory with the copied `kontrol` executable `docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/mnt/go ubuntu sh`
3. Try to run `kontrol`

You will get the "correct" error which stipulates you haven't setup your keys correctly:

```
2018/06/21 19:56:57 cannot read public key file: open : no such file or directory
```

---

Your path forward is probably to figure out why you can't cross-compile

Comment: Yes... if I replace busybox with golang:1.8.3, then it works. For sure in busybox there are some missing dependencies... even it it shouldn't as `go` executable should be self-contained.

Comment: To make it run with `busybox`, I had to compile `kontrol` with `CGO_ENABLED=0`.

Answer (score 1):

If kontrol terminates when you run it with the init flag, then you shuold just use

```
RUN /opt/robotrader/kontrol -init
CMD ["./kontrol"]
```

If it doesn't terminate, you'll have to find another way to architect your appp.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script that runs it twice:

E.g in "startup.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run kontrol twice
./kontrol -initial
./kontrol
```

Then replace the last two lines in your Dockerfile with:

```
COPY startup.sh .
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```