# Not able to use locally built provider in terraform docker image

Tags: docker, terraform-provider-gcp

I have built locally a google terraform provider for adding schema support. When I simply use the binaries with normal Terraform installation on wsl2 and setting up the configs like `.terraformrc` the provider binaries can be used without any issue.

Although when I try to use the binaries in a terraform docker image (copied the binaries under `/go/bin/providers`) even though Terraform says it has been successfully initialized it fails with no such files or directory message.

```
Terraform has been successfully initialized!
 
 You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
 any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
 should now work.
 
 If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
 rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
 commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

 Error: Could not load plugin
 
 
 Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
 
 Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
 resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be
 located,
 don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.
 
 Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
 configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
 requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".
 
 2 problems:
 
 - failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google"
 to obtain schema: fork/exec
 .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.58.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-google_v3.58.0_x5:
 no such file or directory
 - failed to instantiate provider
 "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta" to obtain schema: fork/exec
 .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta/3.64.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-google-beta_v3.64.0_x5:
 no such file or directory
```

The binaries are exists under the right folder:

```
/go/bin/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta/3.64.0/linux_amd64:
total 79768
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Apr 29 21:43 .
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Apr 29 21:43 ..
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      81661207 Apr 29 21:41 terraform-provider-google-beta_v3.64.0_x5

/go/bin/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.58.0/linux_amd64:
total 77320
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Apr 29 21:43 .
drwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          4096 Apr 29 21:43 ..
-rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      79157279 Apr 29 21:42 terraform-provider-google_v3.58.0_x5
```

The symlink is created during init and points to the right target. Permissions granted.

```
/terraform/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta/3.64.0:
 total 12
 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Apr 29 21:59 .
 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Apr 29 21:59 ..
 lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            80 Apr 29 21:59 linux_amd64 -> /go/bin/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta/3.64.0/linux_amd64
   File: '/terraform/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.58.0/linux_amd64' -> '/go/bin/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.58.0/linux_amd64'
   Size: 75         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
 Device: 810h/2064d Inode: 1460422     Links: 1
 Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
 Access: 2021-05-04 12:07:48.516825600 +0000
 Modify: 2021-04-29 21:59:20.960000000 +0000
 Change: 2021-04-29 21:59:20.960000000 +0000
   File: /terraform/.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google/3.58.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-google_v3.58.0_x5
   Size: 79157279   Blocks: 154608     IO Block: 4096   regular file
 Device: 2dh/45d    Inode: 1460171     Links: 1
 Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
 Access: 2021-05-04 12:09:45.596825600 +0000
 Modify: 2021-04-29 21:42:44.000000000 +0000
 Change: 2021-05-04 12:09:45.556825600 +0000
```

CLI config file has the right path:

```
disable_checkpoint = true

provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "/go/bin/providers"
    include = ["*/*/*"]
  }
}
```

Seemingly it should work with the docker image as it does on the local installation but it isn't working.

Can someone point me to the direction what am I missing from the configuration to get the binaries work with the terraform docker image?

Many thanks,
Gabesz

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Try building with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279253/go-compiled-binary-wont-run-in-an-alpine-docker-container-on-ubuntu-host) `CGO_ENABLED=0`