# deploy golang app on docker from ubuntu image (multistage)

Tags: go, ubuntu, docker-compose

using cmd **docker compose up** inside testdocker folder.

getting below **error**
[image]

here is my **dockerfile**

```
# golang base image
FROM golang:1.19-alpine as golangBase
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN go mod tidy && go build -o handlerBuild main.go

FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=golangBase /app .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/handlerBuild" ]
```

here is my **docker-compose.yml**

[image]

having **file structure** like below
/testdocker

/testdocker/main.go

/testdocker/go.mod

/testdocker/dockerfild

/testdocker/docker-compose.yml

**Edit:**
found the solution here, needed flag `CGO_ENABLED=0`, while building.
[Go-compiled binary won't run in an alpine docker container on Ubuntu host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279253/go-compiled-binary-wont-run-in-an-alpine-docker-container-on-ubuntu-host)

Comment: For starters, you're building on Alpine but running on Ubuntu; this is a problem because binaries built on Alpine don't work in most other Linuxes. Also the usual reason for a multistage build is to have a _smaller_ final image, both in size and attack surface. Additionally, your `COPY` in the ubuntu image is incorrect as pointed out in Campbell's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you `COPY --from=golangBase /app .` from `golangBase`, because `golangBase` already has `WORKDIR app`, Docker tries to copy from `/app/app` on `golangBase` (resulting in a file not found error).

Can you try `COPY --from=golangBase . .`? Additionally, because you set `WORKDIR app` on the ubuntu image, I think your entrypoint should just be `ENTRYPOINT ["/handlerBuild"]. In other words, you can think of` WORKDIR app`as telling the Docker image`cd app`so all commands thereafter should be run relative to the`/app` path.

Unrelated note: I'm pretty sure `WORKDIR app` creates the directory `app` and also adds it. So instead of

```
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
```

I'm pretty sure you could just put

```
WORKDIR /app
```

and have the same effect. Correct me if I'm wrong though — I couldn't actually run the Docker build commands because I don't have your source code.

Comment: did everything you said, but still its not working.
now i am getting error like
**Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "handlerBuild": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.**


if i just change 
**ubuntu:latest**
to 
**alpine:latest**

**It works**, but we need ubuntu image only.

Comment: **main.go** just contains a http listerner on **8081**

Comment: My bad can you try `ENTRYPOINT ["./handlerBuild"]` instead? I forgot to include the leading `.`

Comment: Actually I just tried with an example go program locally and `ENTRYPOINT ["./app/handlerBuild"]` should do the trick

Comment: thanks for this! you helped me a lot