# Entrypoint not found in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Given is a very simple `Dockerfile`, build and run on Windows 11. The dockerfile has two stages, first the building stage, and then the actual deployable container.

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go build -o myapp .         # build /app/myapp

FROM alpine:3.14
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /app/myapp /myapp
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]
```

Running the container fails with the following error:

```
/myapp: not found
```

I inspected the first stage, it generated an executable file called `myapp` with `5984` bytes. I can run and execute it there.

I also inspected the second stage and I can verify that `/myapp` exists with `5984` and the correct execution bits. Being in inspection mode via `sh` I cannot execute `/myapp` since it gives me the same error. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: You're building the binary against a Debian-based image, but running against an Alpine image with a different C library stack.  [Go-compiled binary won't run in an alpine docker container on Ubuntu host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279253/go-compiled-binary-wont-run-in-an-alpine-docker-container-on-ubuntu-host) discusses a similar case of building a binary on the host, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I would accept that as an answer. That worked.

Answer (score -2):

There might be several reasons which are causing the issue, try one of the solution:

1. Particularly in Windows 11, running the Alpine Linux image (`alpine:3.14`) might be the issue itself. Try with another image.
2. Try adding the `chmod +x /myapp` before the `ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]` it helps you to check whether `/myapp` is executable inside the container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is no issue running alpine with Windows. If so, Docker would be broken. Additionally, a permission issue would result in a different error.